# displaying HTML with PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

displaying html problem with php & mysql

Hi basically i have a quick mysql_fetch_array script to display the contents from the db like below:

```
$sql_select_jobs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `probid_jobs`");
while ($jobs_found = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_jobs)) {
$template_output .= "<div class=\"listed-jobs\" style=\"border: 1px solid gray; border-bottom: 0px; padding: 20px;\">"; 
$template_output .= "Job Title: " . $jobs_found['job_title'] . "<br />"; 
$template_output .= "Location: " . $jobs_found['location'] . "<br />"; 
$template_output .= "Salary: " . $jobs_found['salary'] . "<br />"; 
$template_output .= "Date Posted: " . $jobs_found['date'] . "<br /><br />"; 
$template_output .= "Description: " . $jobs_found['description'] . "...<a href=\"\">more</a><br />"; 

$template_output .= "</div>";
}
```

however the output would look like this:

```
Job Title: fff
Location: ff
Salary: fff
Date Posted: 18/06/10
Description: <b>fffffffffff <i>fffffffffffffffffff</i><br></b>...more
```

as you can see the description html from the db isn't getting formatted as html, for some reason it is getting escaped.

Comment: Is your `fetch_array` method overwriting anything in your $db class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line:

```
$template_output .= "Description: " . $jobs_found['description'] . "...<a href=\"\">more</a><br />";
```

with:

```
$template_output .= "Description: " . html_entity_decode($jobs_found['description']) . "...<a href=\"\">more</a><br />";
```

More Info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: thankyou that worked perfectly :), could i ask you why u think it was escaping the characters, does mysql_fetch_array not like outputting html?

Comment: @user371999: That is because at the time of insertion of records in database, the html was escaped with their corresponding entities eg `$lt;` for `<` and so on.